# Sort by multiple indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the following array of objects:

```
[
 {
  folder: 'ddd'
 },
 {
  folder: 'aaa'
 },
 {
  file: 'zzz'
 }
]
```

I want to sort it first by file keys, then by folder keys - how can I do this? I have written something like this:

```
var s = function (arr, type) {
  arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aHasKey = false, bHasKey = false;
    var aValue, bValue;
    if (a.hasOwnProperty(type) == true) {
        aHasKey = true;
        aValue = a[type];
    }
    if (b.hasOwnProperty(type) == true) {
        bHasKey = true;
        bValue = b[type];
    }
    if (aHasKey == true && bHasKey == true) {
        if (aValue < bValue) return -1;
        if (aValue == bValue) return 0;
        if (aValue > bValue) return 1;
    } else if (aHasKey == true) {
        return 1;
    } else if (bHasKey == true) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
  });
};
s(arr, 'file');
s(arr, 'folder');
```

But it seems to sort it only by folder, and not by file. How should I do this?

Comment: please add some more data to sort. have all items folder and file keys?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Underscore.js, it is an lightweight JS-Framework with all kind of usefull stuff and it weights only 5.7kb.

http://underscorejs.org/

Then you could do (with priority on file):

```
list = _.sortBy(list, 'folder');
list = _.sortBy(list, 'file');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could chain the sort criteria and use a default string if the property is not set.

```js
var data = [{ folder: 'ddd' }, { folder: 'aaa' }, { file: 'zzz' }];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return (a.file || '').localeCompare(b.file || '') || 
           (a.folder || '').localeCompare(b.folder || '');
})

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

One other way of implementing this job is;

```js
var arr = [{folder: 'iii'}, {folder: 'aaa'}, {file: 'zzz'}, {file: 'ppp'}, {file: 'qqq'},{folder: 'ddd'},{folder: 'sss'},{file: 'aaa'},{folder: 'rrr'},{folder: 'fff'},{file: 'rrr'},{file: 'mmm'}],
 sorted = arr.sort((a,b) => a.file && b.file ? a.file.localeCompare(b.file)
                                             : a.folder && b.folder ? a.folder.localeCompare(b.folder)
                                                                    : a.file ? -1 : 1);
console.log(sorted);
```